# Reading files and printing only the filename in python

Tags: python, file

I am new to python, I need to develop a simple code in which I have to take a directory as a user input and then read all the txt.files in there (containing numbers) then based on the numbers I have to generated an output based on the txt files names.

For example, I have two files one name de and the other is named co, each file contains a number say 1 for co and 2 for de, I need to read the program to read the number from the file, then arrange the output based on the files name and the numbers arranged, which means the output here should be code, as co contains 1 and de contain 2..

This is the code so far as I am getting users directory as input

```
import glob
import os

dirname = input("Please input directory path ")
path = os.path.join(dirname,"**")
for x in glob.glob(path, recursive=True):
    print(x)
```

Comment: you've files with a singular number as their content? Are these files in one specific directory with one level of nesting? Or are there multiple levels of nesting?

Comment: Thank you for replying, no actually, each file different numbers and the files can be in different folders within the directory

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to read from all the matching `.txt` files from your `glob` results. Put everything in a dict and sort it based on the value.

```py
import glob
import os

dirname = input("Please input directory path ")
path = os.path.join(dirname, "**", "*.txt")
fileValues = {}
for x in glob.glob(path, recursive=True):
    with open(x, 'r') as f:
        # Use filename as key and assign its value to it
        fileValues[os.path.basename(x)] = int(f.read())

# Sort the dictionary based on the values and extract the keys in order
sortedFiles = dict(sorted(fileValues.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])).keys()

# sortedFiles is now a list containing all the filenames in ascending order of their values
# Print it, or use it however you want
print(sortedFiles)
```

For your example, `sortedFiles` is now `["co.txt", "de.txt"]`

You can get `"code"` from this by replacing all the `.txt` and joining the list with `''`

```py
''.join(x.replace('.txt', '') for x in sortedFiles)
```